# Having trouble publishing access DB to https SharePoint2010 site with self-signed certificate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, certificate, access-services

Having trouble publishing access DB to https SharePoint2010 site with self-signed certificate.It works find on another site in a different web application using http without certs.  Same problem as 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/f6561747-7184-47ed-a390-2e8939f2d532 Can someone shine some light on this?

Comment: Are there no corresponding ULS entries?  I would also recommend you load up Fiddler  and watch the communication, see what the server is actually returning (if anything), this should tell you if the cert is actually causing your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SharePoint 2010 you'll likely be using IIS7 which won't have **SelfSSL.exe**.

Use `makecert` instead:

```
makecert -r -pe -n 'CN=my.domain.here' -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

Then edit the `https` binding on the website to use the new cert.

Answer (score 1):

The error *"The name of the security certificate is invalid or does not match the name of the site"* comes when the 'common name' in the certificate doesn't match the address you provided in browser to access the site. When you create certificate,using SelfSSl.exe, you have to specify common name(cn), for example as:

```
selfssl.exe /T /N:cn=testsharepoint.com /K:1024 /V:7 /S:1 /P:443
```

If you proceed with the error, most browsers will allow you to go ahead and some (new browsers) will completely deny open your site.

Please try to create new certificate with correct CN or request the site using the CN provided at the time of creating the certificate

Answer (score 0):

Additional info.
MakeCert was installed @ `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Tools`
and I had remove the single quotes around the CN

```
makecert -r -pe -n CN=my.domain.here -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2036 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```